# How to remove duplicate white pegs in Mastermind Game written in C

Tags: c

I am new to C programming and need some help trying to accurately remove duplicate White Pegs in my Mastermind Game written in C, there are 3 Game modes and this is Medium which allows duplicate colours. If the User Enters 'RRGG' and the Randomly generated Values are 'ROYG' I am trying to work out the best way of checking the first 'R' (Which is Black a Peg), so i won't get a white peg for the second one. As you will see below, i'm trying to introduce the concept of a Checking Array, but not sure how to go about it (Although i have attempted it). Any other general coding suggestions would be welcomed and appreciated.

```
#include "masterMindProject.h"

// Declaration of Function Variables & Arrays
int i, j;
int num = 0;
int blackPegCounter = 0;
int whitePegCounter = 0;
int attempts = 15;
int completedAttempts = 0;
int invalidCharFlag = 0;
int checkedBlackArray[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, '\0'};
int checkedWhiteArray[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, '\0'};

char name[MAX_LENGTH + 1];
char colour[NUMCOLS + 1];
char emptyArray[FOURARRAY + 1];
char randomEmptyArray[FOURARRAY + 1];

FILE *fptr;

// Initialise Character Array
colour[0] = 'R';
colour[1] = 'O';
colour[2] = 'Y';
colour[3] = 'G';
colour[4] = 'B';
colour[5] = 'I';
colour[6] = 'V';

// initialize random seed:
srand ( time(NULL) );
system("cls");


// Medium Mode Header
printf("M E D I U M   M O D E\n");
printf("_________________\n");


// Randomly Shuffle the 'colour[]' array and Store the result in the randomEmptyArray[]
for(i=0; i<FOURARRAY; i++)
{
    randomEmptyArray[i] = colour[randFunc()];
    // printf("%c", randomEmptyArray[i]);       

} // End for loop

START: printf("\nHere are the Colours, Please Enter Capital letters only, no spaces: \nR O Y G B I V\n");

do  
{
    blackPegCounter = 0;

    // User enters Values
    printf("\nEnter any 4 from the Above, you have %d Attempts Remaining\n", attempts);
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", emptyArray);
    printf("\n", emptyArray);

    // Validation
    if   (  (emptyArray[0] == 'R' || emptyArray[0] == 'O' || emptyArray[0] == 'Y' || emptyArray[0] == 'G' || emptyArray[0] == 'B'|| emptyArray[0] == 'I' || emptyArray[0] == 'V') ||
            (emptyArray[1] == 'R' || emptyArray[1] == 'O' || emptyArray[1] == 'Y' || emptyArray[1] == 'G' || emptyArray[1] == 'B'|| emptyArray[1] == 'I' || emptyArray[1] == 'V') ||
            (emptyArray[2] == 'R' || emptyArray[2] == 'O' || emptyArray[2] == 'Y' || emptyArray[2] == 'G' || emptyArray[2] == 'B'|| emptyArray[2] == 'I' || emptyArray[2] == 'V') ||
            (emptyArray[3] == 'R' || emptyArray[3] == 'O' || emptyArray[3] == 'Y' || emptyArray[3] == 'G' || emptyArray[3] == 'B'|| emptyArray[3] == 'I' || emptyArray[3] == 'V') )
        {
            printf("\nYou Have chosen correct Colours...");

        }
        else
        {
            printf("Please Enter Valid Characters from the List R O Y G B I V\n");
            goto START;

        } // End of Validation if/else

    printf("\nYou Entered: %s\n", emptyArray);

    // Loop to Check Black Pegs / White Pegs
    for (i=0; i<FOURARRAY; i++)
    {
        if ( emptyArray[i] == randomEmptyArray[i] )
        {
            printf("Black Peg | ");
            blackPegCounter++;
            checkedBlackArray[i]++;
        } 
        else if ( 
                    ( 
                      ( emptyArray[0] == randomEmptyArray[1] ) ||
                      ( emptyArray[0] == randomEmptyArray[2] ) || 
                      ( emptyArray[0] == randomEmptyArray[3] ) 
                    )
                    ||
                    (
                      ( emptyArray[1] == randomEmptyArray[0] ) ||
                      ( emptyArray[1] == randomEmptyArray[2] ) || 
                      ( emptyArray[1] == randomEmptyArray[3] ) 
                    )
                    ||
                    (
                      ( emptyArray[2] == randomEmptyArray[0] ) ||
                      ( emptyArray[2] == randomEmptyArray[1] ) || 
                      ( emptyArray[2] == randomEmptyArray[3] ) 
                    )
                    ||
                    (
                      ( emptyArray[3] == randomEmptyArray[0] ) ||
                      ( emptyArray[3] == randomEmptyArray[1] ) || 
                      ( emptyArray[3] == randomEmptyArray[2] ) 
                    )
                ) 
        {

            checkedWhiteArray[i]++;

            if ( checkedWhiteArray[i] == checkedBlackArray[i] )
            {
                printf("White Peg | ");
                whitePegCounter++;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("----------| ");
            }
        }
    } // End Loop to Check Black Pegs / White Pegs

    attempts--;
    completedAttempts++;

    // Game over if No More Attaempts or Win the Game if 4 Black Pegs
    // If Win, record details and Write to File
    if( attempts == 0)
    {
        printf("\nG A M E   O V E R");
        printf("\nYou have no more Chances");
        break;
    }
    else if( blackPegCounter == 4 )
    {
        printf("\n\nYou Guessed the Sequence and won the Game in %d Attempts", completedAttempts);
        printf("\n\nPlease Enter your Intials: ");
        scanf("%s", &name);

        fptr = fopen (FILENAME, "a");
        if( fptr == NULL )
        {
            printf("\n Could not open the file %s.", FILENAME);
            system("Pause");
            exit(0);

        } //  End of if ( fptr == NULL )

        fscanf(fptr, "%s %d %d", &name, &completedAttempts, &whitePegCounter);
        fprintf(fptr, "\nNAME: %s: Completed in %d Attempt(s) and with %d Whitepegs.", name, completedAttempts, whitePegCounter);
        fclose(fptr);
        break;

    } // End if / else if (Lose, Win Write To File)
}
while( blackPegCounter != 4 );
// End do While

printf("\n\n\n");
system("Pause");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to C and I am currently designing mastermind. I have a different solution of distributing the white pegs.

I have 2 `char` arrays one that stores the color code and one that
stores the guessed colours. Then I use 2 `for` loops and an `if` statement
to check the numbers.

```
// initilising the 2 arrays  

char code[4] = {'r', 'b', 'y', 'o', '\0'};
char guessed[4] = {'b', 'r', 'i', 'v', '\0'};
int i, j, white, black, newwhite;

// in the main
// first for will go through every letter in the color code array

for(i=0; i<4; i++){
    // second for will go through every letter in the guessed color array
    for(j=0; j<4; j++){
        // if there is a match white + 1
        if(code[i] == guessed[j]){
            white++;
            // this will change the found character to z
            // z is a char that doesnt appear in any array
            // you can use any char that is not in the array
            code[j]='z';    
        }
    }
}
```

To sort out black pegs it's just another for with an if and then white - black to get the `newwhite` count.

I hope this helps you even it is a different way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hashmap and put pegs colors as key and number as values , this should make it easier for you .

Comment: Thanks, as i said i'm new to C. How best would i implement this? Or if it's complicated, how best to work with what i have above..